# How can I delete old commits in Github via terminal?

Tags: github

I have a repository.

How can I delete my old commits via terminal? My SSH key is uploaded.

(I'm using github pages, that's why version tracking is not important, don't want to waste Github's storage)

Comment: Hi, you cannot remove old commits on a public repository. You either create a private repo or create a new account.

Answer (score 14):

Deleting the `.git` folder may cause problems in your git repository. If you want to delete all your commit history but keep the code in its current state, it is very safe to do it as in the following:

Checkout

```
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
```

Add all the files

```
git add -A
```

Commit the changes

```
git commit -am "commit message"
```

Delete the branch

```
git branch -D master
```

Rename the current branch to master

```
git branch -m master
```

Finally, force update your repository

```
git push -f origin master
```

PS: this will not keep your old commit history around.

Answer (score 6):

You have an really good answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github

And I quote

> > Note: please see alternative to `git rebase -i` in the comments below—
> >
> > `git reset --soft HEAD^`
>
> First, remove the commit on your local repository. You can do this
>   using `git rebase -i`. For example, if it's your last commit, you can do
>   `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and delete the second line within the editor
>   window that pops up.
>
> Then, force push to GitHub by using `git push origin +master`.
>
> See [Git Magic Chapter 5: Lessons of History - And Then Some](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch05.html#_8230_and_then_some) for more
>   information (i.e. if you want to remove older commits).
>
> Oh, and if your working tree is dirty, you have to do a `git stash`
>   first, and then a `git stash apply` after.

Hope this help you :)

==== EDIT ====

Actually I just reread the post I linked to and specially the comment "word of caution 2" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github

From that I learned that git seems create a new commit and moving the pointer to it, rather than deleting it when using force push. That is if someone already have the SHA1 of your commit, they can still access it. So when taking this into consideration, I must recommend that you do as Tomasz Klim suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new repository.
2. Copy all files to it.
3. Destroy old repository.